# PixelCompare method issue

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an issue with PixelCompare extension.

Here, i am loading it:

```
viewer1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer1'), { extensions: [ 'GoogleMapsLocator', 'Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension','Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension','Autodesk.DocumentBrowser','Autodesk.ToolbarExtension' ,'Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare'] });
```

Then im trying to use it :

```
viewer1.compareTwoModels(data[0],data[1]);
```

Data is an array containing the models.

I get a "viewer.compareTwoModels is not a function" error which means either there is a typo in the function name or it doesnt exist.

Without access to the extension repo, i cannot confirm this method indeed exists.

Im at loss as to what to do and will welcome any help.

EDIT:

This snippet loads the document in the viewer to display it.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${urns[index]}`, function(doc){
var viewables=doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
doc.downloadAecModelData();
viewer1.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
placementTransform: (new THREE.Matrix4()).setPosition({ x: increment, y: 0, z: 0 }),
keepCurrentModels: true,
globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
                        }).then(i => {
                            if(urns.length > 1) {
                                $(viewer1.toolbar.container).find('#toolbarXLS').hide();
                            }
                        });
increment += parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('padding1'));
                        
                    });
```

Then, im using this to pixel compare it:

```
    viewer1.loadModel('urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmwwLS10X0k5UkVhbnNWRXBuLXl5Zmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x', {}, (model1) => {
                    console.log('test load model :' + model1)
                viewer1.loadModel('urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmxXX0dONUJNVDBxdDRuOGZmRWx4SkE_dmVyc2lvbj0x', {}, async (model2) => {
            
                const pcExt = await viewer1.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare');
                pcExt.compareTwoModels(model1, model2);
                console.log()
          });
        });
```

I get an instant "file extension unsupported" error, probably on the first argument the code does not reach `console.log('test load model :' + model1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **compareTwoModels** is part of the extension object, not the viewer - see [PixelCompare extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/pixelcompare-extension)

```
function launchViewer() {
  var options = {
    env: 'Local'
  };

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
      document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), {}
    );

    viewer.start();

    // Load 2 sheets
    viewer.loadModel('scissors1.pdf', {}, (model1) => {
      viewer.loadModel('scissors2.pdf', {}, async (model2) => {
        // Compare them 
        const pcExt = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare');
        pcExt.compareTwoModels(model1, model2);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I confirmed that it is correctly loaded and that the method exists. However, i'm using BIM360 so i cannot really use the file directly like you are. I'm trying to use the urn of the svf file as argument. To get this svfUrn, i'm calling the {urn}/manifest endpoint. Is this the right way?

Comment: You can pass the urn of the given file version you want to show directly to the Viewer - see ForgeViewer.js here https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/3legged/ui

Comment: I think i did this before. I just passed the urn of the current pdf file (ex.: dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmxXX0dONUJNVDBxdDRuOGZmRWx4SkE_dmVyc2lvbj0y ) but it threw a "Unsupported File extension" error. Hence, my trying to use the svf urn (it also seems to be the suggested argument in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/ ) . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you calling Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
And did you prepend "urn:" to "dXJu..." as shown in the sample I linked?

Comment: Yes, i did, I edited my question to show you.

Comment: And are you using `viewer.loadDocumentNode()` instead of `viewer.loadModel()` - as you should if you are using `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load()`? Which exact function returns the error "Unsupported File extension"?

Comment: What files are you trying to compare? PDF files? Sheets in RVT files?

Comment: Also, added code to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/pixelcompare-extension to show how to use Document.load()

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im trying to compare pdf files. The workflow is this: i display the pdf in the viewer using Autodesk.Viewing.Document.Load then i use viewer.loadModel with the urn of the current pdf and another one , just to test it. viewer.loadModel throw the "unsupported file exension". Are you saying i should use viewer.loadDocumentNode instead?

Comment: This confused me: doc.downloadAecModelData(); - since a PDF file has no AEC data. I added even more info to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/pixelcompare-extension which I hope will clarify things

Comment: Thank you, your additon to the docs is what i needed.

Comment: Great!   You're welcome!